# Filter key-value rdd when the value is a list

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have tuples like this:

```
('id1', ['date', 'type', 'value', '2017-11-11 08:32:46.934', 'no_error', '54.64325', '2017-11-11 08:32:47.356', 'no_error', '76.34553']
```

I want to retrieve only the elements that are floats. I have only found solutions for this if the value is just one element not a list, using something along the lines of this:

```
filter(lambda t: is_float(t[1]) == True)
```

being is_float a function I created that, as the name says, returns true if the value is a float. How could I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve it with list comprehension with an if-clause:

```py
def is_float(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

rdd.map(lambda key, list_value: (key, [element for element in list_value if is_float(element)]))
```

This will not be very performant, though.

Update: I changed the code to incorporate the OP's remark, that the list elements are strings.

Comment: Thanks! But it kind of worked. It returns an empty list as value because I found it reads the elements in the list as strings.

Comment: I guess you will then put your function "is_float" instead of the "is instance()", that has some kind of try-except logic inside returning a float if the conversion is possible and otherwise the original string.

Answer (score 1):

That's what `isinstance()` is for. It will return `True` if the first parameter is an instance of the second one.

```python
>>> isinstance(1, float)
False
>>> isinstance("1.0", float)
False
>>> isinstance(1.0, float)
True
```